# PyQt5 Qlabel font size animation

Tags: pyqt5, qlabel

I want to animate PYQt5 QLabel font size. I have tried changing the font size using setFont but is there a way to do animation using QPropertyAnimation?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest it. The animation of a font size is never smooth (different point sizes have different ratios of curves and lines), and the result will always be ugly. You could use a custom widget and a QPainterPath, then apply a QTransform on the painter (or the path) to create a "zoom" effect, but always use the "final" point size as a reference.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante. I'll try to do that. But I'm also thinking of changing font opacity for animation. Thanks again.